# Adding NaoQI API to the PYTHONPATH

Tags: ros, python, naoqi, nao, pythonpath

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,
I am currently using naoQi-sdk-1.14. I am also following the guide: **http://www.ros.org/wiki/nao/Tutorials/Getting-Started**

I am on the stage: 1.6: Launching ROS and NAOqi

When I execute the command:

> LD_LIBRARY_PATH=~/naoqi/naoqi-sdk-1.14-linux32/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH NAO_IP=127.0.0.1 roslaunch nao_driver
> nao_driver_sim.launch

I get the following error:

> "Error importing NaoQI. Please make
> sure that Aldebaran's NaoQI API is in
> your PYTHONPATH"

The full output is shown below:

> martin@martin-VPCEE2S1E:~$
> > LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/martin/naoqi/naoqi-sdk-1.14-linux32/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH NAO_IP=127.0.0.1 roslaunch nao_driver
> nao_driver_sim.launch ... logging to
> /home/martin/.ros/log/3b3e0ce8-641c-11e2-b2a9-78dd08e5b016/roslaunch-martin-VPCEE2S1E-9508.log
> Checking log directory for disk usage.
> This may take awhile. Press Ctrl-C to
> interrupt Done checking log file disk
> usage. Usage is <1GB.
>
> started roslaunch server
> http://martin-VPCEE2S1E:59489/
>
> ## SUMMARY
>
> PARAMETERS  *
> /nao_sensors/use_joint_sensors  *
> /rosdistro  * /rosversion
>
> NODES   /
> nao_controller (nao_driver/nao_controller.py)
> nao_sensors (nao_driver/nao_sensors.py)
> nao_walker (nao_driver/nao_walker.py)
>
> ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311
>
> core service [/rosout] found Exception
> AttributeError:
> AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object
> has no attribute '_Thread__block'",)
> in <module 'threading' from
> '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'>
> ignored process[nao_walker-1]: started
> with pid [9528] Exception
> AttributeError:
> AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object
> has no attribute '_Thread__block'",)
> in <module 'threading' from
> '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'>
> ignored process[nao_sensors-2]:
> started with pid [9529] Exception
> AttributeError:
> AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object
> has no attribute '_Thread__block'",)
> in <module 'threading' from
> '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'>
> ignored process[nao_controller-3]:
> started with pid [9530] No handlers
> could be found for logger "rosout"
> [ERROR] [WallTime: 1358809992.968376]
> Error importing NaoQI. Please make
> sure that Aldebaran's NaoQI API is in
> your PYTHONPATH.
> ================================================================================REQUIRED process [nao_walker-1] has died!
> process has died [pid 9528, exit code
> 1, cmd
> /home/martin/my_workspace/nao/stacks/nao_robot/nao_driver/scripts/nao_walker.py
> --pip=127.0.0.1 --pport=9559 __name:=nao_walker __log:=/home/martin/.ros/log/3b3e0ce8-641c-11e2-b2a9-78dd08e5b016/nao_walker-1.log].
> log file:
> /home/martin/.ros/log/3b3e0ce8-641c-11e2-b2a9-78dd08e5b016/nao_walker-1*.log
> Initiating shutdown!
> ================================================================================ Traceback (most recent call last):
> File
> "/home/martin/my_workspace/nao/stacks/nao_robot/nao_driver/scripts/nao_sensors.py",
> line 46, in 
> from nao_msgs.msg import TorsoOdometry, TorsoIMU ImportError:
> No module named nao_msgs.msg Traceback
> (most recent call last):   File
> "/home/martin/my_workspace/nao/stacks/nao_robot/nao_driver/scripts/nao_controller.py",
> line 46, in 
> import nao_msgs.msg ImportError: No module named nao_msgs.msg
> [nao_controller-3] killing on exit
> [nao_sensors-2] killing on exit
> [nao_walker-1] killing on exit
> shutting down processing monitor...
> ... shutting down processing monitor
> complete done

I have looked at similar questions and answers such as http://answers.ros.org/question/28902/adding-naoqi-api-to-pythonpath-v112/?answer=29878#post-id-29878.

I have added onto my bashrc file -
**export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=~/my_workspace/nao:$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH**
and **export PYTHONPATH=~/naoqi/naoqi-sdk-1.14-linux32/lib:$PYTHONPATH**
but i still get this error :S

Could anyone help please?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/52950/adding-naoqi-api-to-the-pythonpath/) by [JustARandomGuy](https://answers.ros.org/users/3963/justarandomguy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2013-01-21

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You don't need the naoqi-sdk-X.YY-linux32 but the NaoQI Python SDK for the ROS nodes, starting with NaoQI 1.12. So, don't add it to your LD_LIBRARY_PATH globally in your .bashrc (that may have other dangerous side effects).

You need to have the separate Python SDK in your PYTHONPATH, that alone should be enough. Here is what my entries in .bashrc look like:

```
export AL_DIR=$HOME/code/Nao/1.12.3
export PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:$AL_DIR/pynaoqi"
```

The directory  `~/code/Nao/1.12.3/pynaoqi` contains the files allib.py, allog.py, naoqi.py etc.

---

Originally posted by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) with karma: 5904 on 2013-01-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1